# Script to batch rename to retain only some characters of original filename?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, file-rename

I need to rename thousands of rar files with original filenames of variable sizes. I must make them 10 characters long by keeping the first 3 and the last 4 characters of the original filename and adding in the middle 3 random characters [numbers].

#### Example:

#### input:

"John Doe - Jane Doe - 19073275.rar"

"XXXX - XYXY- 98705674.rar

#### output:

"Joh1273275.rar"

"XXX9795674.rar"

Next, the .bat should generate a .txt with the original name and the modified one underneath for each file!

I know it's possible but I'm completely stupid when it comes to writing it. Please help!

Comment: Try Bulk Rename Here: http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch file below do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.rar) do (
   set name=%%~Na
   set num=00!random!
   set newName=!name:~0,3!!num:~-3!!name:~-4!
   ren "%%a" "!newName!%%~Xa"
   echo "%%a" modified to "!newName!%%~Xa" >> log.txt
)
```

Comment: Aacini, thank you! That is exactly what i need! In spite of my efforts, I couldn't get it right with the random stuff. This works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a script to generate the names in any simple way (say first 6 + last 4), and then check for any duplicates to be cleaned up by hand (or a second pass shifting the middle, or ...). Unless this is a repetitive job (do it daily), it isn't worth fully automatizing.

Comment: Manually is not an option - thousands of files. This might just become a repetitive job. But I'll try to sketch up a script folowing your suggestion, i.e. first 6- last 4 and see where this leads...